# Getting back the old Google search results without the favicons of 2019?

Tags: google-search

Google did some redesign so that *domain icons* appear with the results:

[image]

Any ideas if there is a way to get the old formatting back (where there is an actual URL, without the favicon, below the title of the page)?

I wish they had something like `google.com/search?intf=v1&...`, where the `intf` would specify the version of the interface you want to use.

Comment: I was also confronted with this yesterday Sun 6 Oct at my home PC. It indeed looks very messy. However, today Mon 7 Oct I don't see this, but I'm at my work PC now. Both are Win10 machines using FireFox.

Comment: [Here](https://www.lockedownseo.com/why-google-added-favicons-search-results/) is someone who states *This was not a feature that was added to make the search results “better” for the users. Favicons were added to make AdWords blend In more*. That is indeed the effect it has: it takes much more effort to distinguish ads from real info. The organic search results and paid ad results now have a similar-sized icon in the same place. The author even calls this a [dark pattern](https://www.darkpatterns.org/).

Comment: Take a look [here](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-fix-googles-ugly-logo-filled-search-results-1841062453): it removes the icon and the arrow, but the large whitespace remains unfortunately.